# Getting "A network error occurred" when using back button from page linked with data-ajax=false

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get my jQuery Mobile site to run on Android (testing with Galaxy S3 right now, Android 4.0.4) using PhoneGap.

I'm getting an Application Error saying "A network error occurred. ..." when trying to use the device's "Back" button to get back to the homepage of my site.  The page I'm returning from is one that was initially linked to using "data-ajax=false".

I can replicate the error as follows:

1. Launch application, which starts at index.html
2. Click a link that **does not** use data-ajax=false, for example help.html
3. Use the device's back button to return to index.html
4. Click on a link that **does** use data-ajax=false, name irrelevant
5. Try to use the device's back button to return to index.html

The exact error it throws is:

> A network error occurred. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/android_asset/www/help.html

Strangely, if I do not visit another page before going to my "data-ajax=false" linked page, it throws no error, and the page works as expected.

I can't seem to find any resources online on a solution.

I've tried setting $.support.cors and $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true in index.html but that did nothing.  The only difference between the two links is that one has data-ajax=false and the other does not.  I reproduced the error with two identical pages, so I'm certain the content of the pages does not matter.

Here's how I'm linking the pages:

```
<a href="help.html">Help</a>
```

and

```
<a href="test.html" data-ajax="false">Test</a>
```

Any advice would be appreciated, or an explanation of what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably avoid using data-ajax="false" in phonegap apps - since it causes a full page reload, you'll lose state and be reinitializing the phonegap scripts on each page rather than just on app startup.

Although I can't be 100% sure, there is likely a connection to why the url doesn't work at that point - android_asset probably isn't really the root folder of the device, and triggering a load of /android_asset/www/help.html from a partially initialized page may not work as expected.

If you don't visit an ajax page first, there is no hash on the url and it is just a regular load of index.html, same as when you start the app.